# EF 4.1 stored procedure not available?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

The Ado.NET Team has recently [release the version fo EF 4.1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/03/15/ef-4-1-release-candidate-available.aspx) they said that stored procedure are not available!! But Raw SQL queries are still supporting stored procedure right?

```
var rs = db.Database.SqlQuery<Doc>(
            "EXECUTE docsByPeriod @param={0}", parameters: period).ToList();
```

So this code will work or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can execute any SQL (including stored procedures) by `SqlQuery`. The announcement about not supported SP means that you can't map SP procedures to Insert, Update, Delete operations performed on your entity as currently possible in EDMX.